# Difference between methods of abstract and methods of non-abstract in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, abstract-class, difference, abstract-methods

In C#, In an abstract class, provided method1 implementation and method2 as abstract. I can override both method1 and method2 in child classes. Then, what is the difference between abstract method and non-abstract method.

```
 abstract class baseclass
    {
        public void nonabstract_method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("non abstract method in base class with implementation");
        }
        public abstract void abstract_method();//abstract method declaration

    }
    class childClass1: baseclass
    {
        public void nonabstract_method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("non abstract method in child class 1 with implementation");
        }
        public override void abstract_method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("abstract method in child class 1 with implementation");
        }
    }
    class childClass2 : baseclass
    {   


        public void nonabstract_method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("non abstract method in child class 2 with implementation");
        }
        public override void abstract_method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("abstract method in child class 2 with implementation");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            childClass2 objClass2 = new childClass2();
            objClass2.nonabstract_method();
            objClass2.abstract_method();

            childClass1 objClass1 = new childClass1();
            objClass1.nonabstract_method();
            objClass1.abstract_method();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You don't see the difference between a method with a body and one without? Read up on the official documentation and clarify what precisely you have a problem with. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435(v=vs.71).aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/sf985hc5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are not overriding those methods. You are *hiding* them (pay attention to compiler warnings!). For example, if you change your test code to the following:

```
baseclass objClass2 = new childClass2();
objClass2.nonabstract_method();
objClass2.abstract_method();
```

You will get the output:

> non abstract method in base class with implementation
>   abstract method in child class 2 with implementation

`nonabstract_method()` must be marked *virtual*, and your subclasses must use the keyword *override*  to properly override the method. In this case, there is no difference between `abstract` and `non-abstract`, other than the fact that an `abstract` method *does not have an implementation*, and the method is not overridden, but implemented by the sub classes.

Comment: What is the advantage of overriding a method  than hiding a method in the child classes ?

Comment: @MohanJegadeesan Because the overriden method will be called even when cast as the base class - compare my example with yours. Other than that, you'd probably get a better understanding by reading up on polymorphism than I could explain here

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in your code is not overriding the non abstract and abstract methods, you are simply hiding them. A *real* override should contain the `override` keyword.

> I can override both method1 and method2 in child classes

No. Because you think "override" means "hiding", you think abstract and non abstract methods are the same. Actually, abstract methods can be overridden but non abstract methods *cannot* be overridden! Only methods marked with `virtual`, `override` or `abstract` can be overridden but *all* method can be *hidden*.

So what is overriding and what is hiding? Consider these two classes:

```
public class Hide {
    public void method () {
        Console.WriteLine("Original");
    }
}

public class Override {
    public virtual void method() {
        Console.WriteLine("Original");
    }
}
```

If you inherit `Hide` and hide `method`, inherit `Override` and override `method`, the two subclasses will look like this:

```
public class SubHide {
    public void method () {
        Console.WriteLine("Hidden!");
    }
}

public class SubOverride {
    public override void method() {
        Console.WriteLine("Overridden!");
    }
}
```

Now consider these 6 objects, what will be printed if their `method`s are called?

```
Hide hide1 = new Hide(); // Original
Hide hide2 = new SubHide(); // Original
SubHide hide3 = new SubHide(); //Hidden!

Override override1 = new Override(); // Original
Override override2 = new SubOverride(); // Overridden!
SubOverride override3 = new SubOverride(); // Overridden!
```

Now can you see the difference between the two?

Abstract methods also don't contain an implementation on its own. It actually *must* be overridden for it to function properly. That is why you cannot instantiate an abstract class directly, you must instantiate a subclass of an abstract class, because abstract classes contains unimplemented methods.

Conclusion: **The biggest difference between abstract and non abstract method is that abstract methods can either be hidden or overridden, but non abstract methods can only be hidden. And that abstract methods don't have an implementation, not even an empty pair of curly braces.**

Comment: In what real time scenarios, I need to hide a method? and In What real time scenarios, I need to override a method?

Comment: @MohanJegadeesan I don't use hiding that much, and I don't think you would do this often either. And I recommend you to override `ToString` in your classes because it can be helpful when you are debugging. Also, you need to override methods when you are inheriting from an abstract class. I once wrote a Chinese chess winforms app. I created an abstract class called `ChessPiece` and all the different chess pieces inherit from it and override the required methods. Does that answer your question? If yes, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick!

Comment: why hiding principle is included in the child classes of an abstract class. it could be allowed only abstract principle for the child classes of an abstract class. but hiding facility is also included while inheriting the abstract class. My question is, why this feature hiding is included for what purpose? could you answer me in which real time scenario in the application development, at which situation I must use hiding?

Comment: @MohanJegadeesan sometimes you would want to inherit from a class in the .NET framework. And you would want to override some of its method and properties in order to add some of your own logic into it. But because the methods or properties are not marked `virtual`, you are unable to do so. You can only hide the original implementation and add your new implementation. For example, you want to add some functionality to `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` and you want to override the `Text` property but you can't. You can only hide it because it is not marked as `virtual`.